# MongoDB updateOne Array in array

Tags: python, mongodb

I´m lookiing for update one field, array in array

```
db.germain.updateOne({}, {$set: { "items.$[elem].sub_items.price" : 2}}, {arrayFilters: [ { "elem.sub_item_name": "my_item_two_one" } ] } )
```

I find one but it doesn´t update.

```
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("4faaba123412d654fe83hg876"),
            "user_id" : 123456,
            "items" : [
                    {
                            "item_name" : "my_item_one",
                            "sub_items" : [
                                          {
                                          "sub_item_name" : "my_item_one_one",
                                          "price" : 20
                                          },
                                          ]
                    },
                    {
                            "item_name" : "my_item_two",
                            "sub_items" : [
                                          {
                                          "sub_item_name" : "my_item_two_one",
                                          "price" : 30
                                          },
                                          {
                                          "sub_item_name" : "my_item_two_two",
                                          "price" : 50
                                          },
                                          ]
                    }
                     ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually its nested array. So you need to specify which object in the parent array to be changed? and which object in the ***specified** object of parent array* to be changed.

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  $set: {
    "items.$[parent].sub_items.$[child].price": 2
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
      {  "parent.item_name": "my_item_two" },
      {  "child.sub_item_name": "my_item_two_one" }
    }
  ]
})
```

If you need o to change the whole object in parent array, simply you can use `$` positional operator.

Comment: @GermainFr Consider to approve the answer which may help to developers.